# Logging to Application Insights

Tags: logging, application-insights

I am trying to add Application Insights telemetry to a SiteCore project in Visual Studio 2019 using the steps documented in the following article, and have configured the connection string in the generated ApplicationInsights.config file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net

However I do not see any page requests appear in the AppInsights instance when running the solution locally from my dev machine.

Are there any special configuration steps or packages specific for SiteCore to setup this logging?

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!